# What way is there to set up my iframe so it cuts out the border of my camera and just displays the video

Tags: html, css, iframe

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
<iframe id="frame" src="https://cam.scrantonlive.com" width="800" height="450" frameborder="500"></iframe>
  </body>
</html>
```

I am setting up my camera stream in an `iframe` and I want to position it so I can just see the camera with the control.

I have tried resizing the `iframe` but it just does nothing and doesn't adjust.